# Error when trying to load .json in webpage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to show the data from a json file in a web page but I get this error.

This is my test.cshtml, the error is on the `@foreach` line:

```
@model API_STA_1.Classes.Description

@{
    ViewData["description"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>

            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.projects)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", new { /*id = item.PrimaryKey*/}) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /*id = item.PrimaryKey*/}) |
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: you need to show controller action code

Comment: @EhsanSajjad this one? https://codeshare.io/G8x64v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing Model object to the view from your controller action.

you will need to pass it back to the view.

See:

```
var description = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Description>>(json);

return View(description);
```

Secodnly you don't need to specify the view fully qualified path with name as by convention it will look in **Views** folder a folder named **Test** and then view file named **test.cshtml** based on your controller class name and action name.

**UPDATE:**
OP was getting error about view not found so the following worked for him:

```
return View("test/test.cshtml", description);
```

Comment: So i changed it to `description` but now i get an error because it's looking for test.cshtml in the views folder but i don't have a views folder. https://imgur.com/a/KDYZEBT

Comment: @T.v.A. then try what you did already: `return View("test/test.cshtml",description);`

Comment: That works! Thank you. I'm new to this and this was a big help!

Comment: @T.v.A. no problem and welcome, the code in the answer should work, but you probably have something missing in startup so that's why we need to explicitly specify the path of view otherwise it works by convention